# Compile error during workbook open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which uses a certain type, let's call it T, that's in a module (DLL) defined in my References -- all good.

I created some code that's called in Workbook_Open() that will add a reference to the DLL if it's not already in the list of references. This is so I can give the workbook to someone and they won't have to deal with creating the reference by hand.

My problem is that when I open the workbook (double-click), before Workbook_Open() gets executed (and the Refence can be set) I get thrown into the debugger which points to and complains that type T, defined in the not-yet-referenced DLL, is not defined. Well no kidding it's not.

This seems a little chick and egg. Anyone seen this before? How did you fix it?

Comment: Are you using type T anywhere in the workbook_open code (or in any of the worksheet objects?) During compile it will check to see if strong typed objects are ok. one way to get around this is to abandon strong typing your T objects.

Comment: As @Pynner suggests, use late binding. So instead of declaring a variable of type T, declare is as ``Object``.

Comment: Further to what Rachel suggested. Does the user also has that dll? Is it registered on his pc?

Comment: The DLL IS registered on the machine, The type T is NOT used in Workbook__Open. When I double-click the workbook, when opening I get the error and thrown into a a Class which declares T though this class is not references in Workbook_Open()

Comment: So it would appear that the compiler also compiles all of the classed as well. Can you try late binding in your class?

Answer (score 1):

Like other people have said, if you are not going to add the reference to the DLL until  `Workbook_Open`, you have to use late binding to connect to the stuff in the DLL.

However, I think you are going about this the wrong way. Instead of adding a reference to the DLL in `Workbook_Open`, have it already referenced and check `.IsBroken` instead. Then you can have code to do what ever is needed to fix the broken reference.

This keeps the benefit of early binding and you won't get the same kind of compile errors if the reference to the DLL is broken.

**NOTE**: You can still get compile errors, but they won't be for the missing DLL. While you have a broken reference, any use of functions from the VBA `Strings` module will trigger a compile error if the function isn't prefaced with `Strings.` For example, the following code will cause a compiler error before `Workbook_Open` runs if you have any broken references.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim r As Reference
   For Each r In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
      If r.IsBroken Then
         MsgBox "Found broken reference." & vbCrLf _
              & Mid(r.FullPath, InStrRev(r.FullPath, "\") + 1)
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

To fix, prefix `Mid` and `InStrRev` with  `Strings.`.

```
MsgBox "Found broken reference." & vbCrLf _
     & Strings.Mid(r.FullPath, Strings.InStrRev(r.FullPath, "\") + 1)
```