# VBA compile error due to Reference not yet loaded

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

My Excel spreadsheet has a module (called MyModule) that requires a Reference to be added in order to work. If that Reference is not loaded, I will get this error upon opening the workbook:

`Compile error in hidden module: MyModule`

So I tried to add the following to `Workbook_Open()` in `ThisWorkbook`, such that the Reference will be added upon workbook open:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile pathToMyReference
```

However, I am still getting the same compile error message. Is there a way to truly add the Reference before the spreadsheet is open?

Comment: You can resolve the binding problem by using "late binding"

Comment: I am aware of "late binding", but is there any other way out?

Comment: [Doesn't look like it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9221566/4604845), if you disregard setting the reference in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how well this would work, but you could try setting the reference like you're doing now and then [import the actual code at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402312/4604845).